# Is it feasible to still have wooden elements with possible termite threat

Tags: wood, materials

I'm planning on getting a house built and I would like to incorporate a good amount of wooden elements similar to japanese house designs but I'm worried of possible termite infestation. Is it feasible to still have wooden elements with possible termite threat?

I'm on a tropical country and I don't know if that changes the materials/design standards.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have unusual termites, the threat is wood in contact with soil. You need concrete (or a similar material that termites can't chew through) between the soil and the wood. You should also inspect the foundation every so often to check for termite tunnels. (Termites dry out easily, so they'll build a tunnel on the outside of the concrete in order to get from soil to the wood.)

The design of the exterior and interior of the home is completely irrelevant. What matters is the foundation/crawlspace/etc, and you should use whatever style is appropriate for the region, and allows for inspection of the foundation.